# set(sorted()) method in python

Tags: python, sorting, set

When I used sorted on the set in python it returns sorted list. But I want to return the set. I tried `set(sorted())` but it doesn't sort the set.
I tried another way. But why set(sorted()) isn't sorting the set?

[my tried code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqKPV.png)

Comment: Can you please share your code without inserting any image in Question

Comment: Please post your code directly in your question here.

Comment: The definition of a `set`: A set is an **unordered collection** with no duplicate elements.

Comment: `set` objects have no order. If you require any particular order, then you cannot use a `set`. What you are asking for doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Sets are *unsorted,* that is their nature. Taking a set (or any collection) then sorting it, then making a set out of that, will be unlikely to produce sorted results.

If you require the items in a sorted manner, you should turn them into something that *can* be sorted (like a list, which is what you get from `sorted(someSet)`). For example:

```py
>>> a = {100, 99, 1, 2, 5, 6}    # A set

>>> sorted(a)                    # A sorted list from that set.
[1, 2, 5, 6, 99, 100]

>>> set(sorted(a))               # An (unsorted) set from that sorted list.
{1, 2, 99, 100, 5, 6}
```

Comment: Thankyou for answer. I tried it. But my question is Why the set(sorted()) doesn't sort the list?

Comment: `sorted` does sort the list! Then you put the result of the sorting in a set and now it's unordered again.

Comment: @Jidnyasa: because, as I  explain in the first paragraph, turning a sorted collection back into a set makes it unsorted again. Sets are unordered, regardless of the order of the thing you make them from.